# What is the ideal way to design this Apache Beam transform that outputs multiple files including binary outputs?

Tags: java, apache-beam

I am trying to process PDF files in a Beam pipeline coming from an input bucket, and output the results, input, and intermediate file all to a separate output bucket.

[image: My pipeline]

The filenames of all three outputs are derived from the final step, and there is a 1:1 mapping of input files to output filenames, so I don't want to have shard templates in the output filenames (my UniquePrefixFileNaming class is doing the same thing as TextIO.withoutSharding())

Since the filenames are only known in the last step, I don't think I can set up tagged outputs and output files in each of the previous processing steps - I have to carry data all the way through the pipeline.

What is the best way of achieving this?  Below is my attempt at the problem - the text outputs work okay but I don't have a solution for the PDF output (no binary output sink available, no binary data carried through).  Is FileIO.writeDynamic the best approach?

```java
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();

        PCollection<MyProcessorTransformResult> transformCollection = p.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern("Z:\\Inputs\\en_us\\**.pdf"))
                .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
                .apply(TikaIO.parseFiles())
                .apply(ParDo.of(new MyProcessorTransform()));

        // Write output PDF
        transformCollection.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern())
        transformCollection.apply(FileIO.<String, MyProcessorTransformResult>writeDynamic()
                .withTempDirectory("Z:\\Temp\\vbeam")
                .by(input -> input.data.getResourceKey())
                .via(
                        Contextful.fn((SerializableFunction<MyProcessorTransformResult, byte[]>) input -> new byte[] {})
                )
                .withNaming(d -> new UniquePrefixFileNaming(d, ".pdf"))
                .withNumShards(1)
                .withDestinationCoder(ByteArrayCoder.of())
                .to("Z:\\Outputs"));

        // Write output TXT
        transformCollection.apply(FileIO.<String, MyProcessorTransformResult>writeDynamic()
                .withTempDirectory("Z:\\Temp\\vbeam")
                .by(input -> input.data.getResourceKey())
                .via(
                        Contextful.fn((SerializableFunction<MyProcessorTransformResult, String>) input -> input.originalContent),
                        TextIO.sink()
                )
                .withNaming(d -> new UniquePrefixFileNaming(d, ".pdf.txt"))
                .withNumShards(1)
                .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
                .to("Z:\\Outputs"));

        // Write output JSON
        transformCollection.apply(FileIO.<String, MyProcessorTransformResult>writeDynamic()
                .withTempDirectory("Z:\\Temp\\vbeam")
                .by(input -> input.data.getResourceKey())
                .via(
                        Contextful.fn((SerializableFunction<MyProcessorTransformResult, String>) input -> SerializationHelpers.toJSON(input.data)),
                        TextIO.sink()
                )
                .withNaming(d -> new UniquePrefixFileNaming(d, ".pdf.json"))
                .withNumShards(1)
                .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
                .to("Z:\\Outputs"));

        p.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own File sink that saves all 3 outputs.  FileIO is very much tailored towards streaming, having Windows and Panes to split the data up, - my sink step kept running out of memory because it would try to aggregate everything before doing any actual writes, as batch jobs run in a single Window in Beam.  I had no such issues with my custom DoFn.

My recommendation for anyone looking into this is to do the same - you could try to hook into Beam's Filesystems classes or look at jclouds for filesystem agnostic storage.